# What are good digital document filing/archiving solutions?

Tags: pdf, archiving, document-management

We're looking to digitize a lot of our physical paperwork and organize the paperwork we already have in digital format in a better way.
Currently we are using Dropbox for Business but are looking for a better solution that lets us:

- Categorize & Tag documents
- Provide access controls
- On-Premise is preferred over cloud based due to sensitivity of the data (legal documents, bank statements, contracts, etc.)
- Ability to index pdf documents and make them searchable (similar to Evernote - would be great but not absolutely required)
- Create full set backups

What options are out there, I couldn't find anything that like a good fit but I'm sure there must be solutions that e.g. legal offices, etc. use?

Comment: Shopping questions are considered off topic.  Please check the FAQ

Answer (score 1):

Two options come to mind.

1. Why not just use Windows's built in features and Adobe Acrobat?

In Windows Vista, 7, and 8 tagging documents is really easy, and with group policy, so is providing access to folders (where the documents saved based on category.)  Adobe Acrobat can easily search multiple PDF documents at once, and creating backups is as easy as copying the files to a USB drive (with or without software to do it automatically).  And it's all 100% local.

Use [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com).

With Google docs, uploading and categorizing files is super easy and straightforward, and with Google Drive (all Google Docs are stored in the [Google Drive](http://drive.google.com)) keeping an extra copy is also incredibly easy to setup.  Google is arguably has the best searching algorithms, and will be able to index your files for you.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_management_system, and http://www.dzone.com/links/8_best_open_source_document_management_systems.html for some references. Google gives _lots_ of hits, analyze alternatives them carefully (you'll have to live with what you select for _years_, moving your data into it will be lots of work, and it could be very hard to migrate if the need arises later).